# java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\Report\testQuery.xlsx (The system cannot find the path specified) after deploying file in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am running a cron scheduler which going to run the query and export into excel file in resource folder. When I'm running the program in IDE it is working fine and file is getting created under resource, but when i deploy the code in Tomcat getting this error "java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\Report\testQuery.xlsx (The system cannot find the path specified)"

Output from IDE :
Starting
Connected
Executing
Exported Successfully
Closed

Output from Tomcat :

Starting
Connected
Executing
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\Report\testQuery.xlsx (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: xlsxWorkbook.write(new FileOutputStream("src/main/resources/Report/testQuery.xlsx"));

Comment: Instead of hard coding the file path, define it in a properties file and bind the corresponding property in the service or component where you are performing the export.

Comment: If your using springframework you can use either ResourceLoader or ResourceUtils for get file object from resource path. Path string will be "classpath:/Report/testQuery.xlsx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder *src\main\resources\Report* does not exist when you deploy the application to Tomcat. When the project is built, compiled classes and resources are packed into a WAR archive. On runtime, you can access resources from the /resources folder, but you cannot write there.

You need to find some other location for the generated files, ensuring that it will be available for your application when deployed to the application server.

- If the files are temporary, you can use `File.createTempFile`, which is pretty safe to be used in any environment.
- You can use your application's working directory, whatever it is. In your IDE it would be your project's root folder (that's why *src\main\resources\Report\testQuery.xlsx* works), on Tomcat it depends on the server configuration (CATALINA_BASE environment variable). You could create there a */Report* subdirectory on the application startup.